# Snowflake dynamic SQL: Equivalent of DBMS_SQL/sp_executesql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-sql

**I am searching for equivalent of [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)/[DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-C96D5BAA-29A9-4AB5-A69E-E31228ECC9E9) that would allow to execute dynamic SQL(ideally with binded parameters).**

Rationale behind: **Generate the code to be run in SQL and execute from SQL**

I am aware that Snowflake does not have procedural SQL component including control flow syntax(WHILE/IF-THEN/TRY-CATCH) and such constructs can be mitigated with JavaScript code inside stored procedure.

---

Sample scenario:

Generating **arbitrary SQL**: here table generation

```
SELECT create_table_sql FROM ( 
 SELECT LISTAGG(REPLACE(CHAR(13) || ',a<index> INT DEFAULT UNIFORM(1, 10000, RANDOM())', '<index>', seq8()+1),'')
       WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY seq8()) AS column_list
   
   ,REPLACE(REPLACE(
          'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <table_name>(id INT  <column_list>);'
          ,'<table_name>', 'wide5')
          ,'<column_list>', column_list) AS create_table_sql
 FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => 5))
);
```

Output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE wide5(id INT  
,a1 INT DEFAULT UNIFORM(1, 10000, RANDOM())
,a2 INT DEFAULT UNIFORM(1, 10000, RANDOM())
,a3 INT DEFAULT UNIFORM(1, 10000, RANDOM())
,a4 INT DEFAULT UNIFORM(1, 10000, RANDOM())
,a5 INT DEFAULT UNIFORM(1, 10000, RANDOM()));
```

Now the goal is to execute it from WebUI. My first idea was to assign it to variable. It failed due to size limitations(minor setback):

```
SET sql_text = (SELECT create_table_sql FROM ...);
```

> Assignment to 'SQL_TEXT' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 260; the limit is 256 (internal storage size in bytes).

Here should be something like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE/EXEC` or their parametrized counterparts known from other RDBMS.

```
....(generated_code)
```

---

I created my own oversimplifed version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE execute_immediate(sql_param STRING)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$
 var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: SQL_PARAM});   
 return 'Done.';
$$;
```

And pass subquery directly as a parameter(here Snowflake shines):

```
CALL execute_immediate(subquery);
```

Example:

```
CALL execute_immediate(
 SELECT create_table_sql 
 FROM ( 
  SELECT LISTAGG(REPLACE(CHAR(13) || ',a<index> INT DEFAULT UNIFORM(1, 10000, RANDOM())', '<index>', seq8()+1),'') 
       WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY seq8()) AS column_list
   
   ,REPLACE(REPLACE(
          'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <table_name>(id INT  <column_list>);'
          ,'<table_name>', 'wide5')
          ,'<column_list>', column_list) AS create_table_sql
 FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => 5)))
);
```

Checking the SELECT query: `SELECT * FROM wide5` as the table was created.

It is working, but I am sure it could be done much better.

---

Other considerations and alternatives that I tried and found not fully satisfying:

- generate SQL script, exec query, copy output, paste and execute (it requires manual step)
- writing code-generation part inside JavaScript stored procedure(maybe, if really no other ways available)

Dynamic SQL may be tricky to write and error-prone but with parameter binding/quoting identifiers and limiting user input is still safe.

Comment: Did you consider referencing the last query results? Like in `last_query_id(-2)` https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c

Comment: Have a look at variable substitution, from SnowSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using **[Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html)**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wide5;

-- to be run with Snowsight
DECLARE
    SQL STRING;
BEGIN
    SELECT create_table_sql 
    INTO :SQL 
    FROM ( 
     SELECT LISTAGG(REPLACE(CHAR(13) || ',a<index> INT DEFAULT UNIFORM(1, 10000, RANDOM())'
           , '<index>', seq8()+1),'')
           WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY seq8()) AS column_list

       ,REPLACE(REPLACE(
              'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <table_name>(id INT  <column_list>);'
              ,'<table_name>', 'wide5')
              ,'<column_list>', column_list) AS create_table_sql
     FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => 5))
    );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQL;
END;


SELECT * FROM wide5;
-- ID   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
```